# How to pass a variable to an awk print parameter

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying extract the `nth + 1` and `nth + 3` columns from a file.

This is what tried, which is a useful pseudo code:

```
for i in {1..100} ; do awk -F "," " { printf \"%3d, %12.3f, %12.3f\\n\", \$1, \$($i+1), \$($i+3) } " All_Runs.csv > Run-$i.csv
```

which, obviously doesn't work (but it seemed reasonable to hope).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid some hairy quoting and escaping by using awk to do the incrementing:

```
awk -F "," 'BEGIN { i = j = 1 } { i++; j+=3; printf "%3d, %12.3f, %12.3f\n", $1, $i, $j > Run-$i.csv }' All_Runs.csv
```

Or by using awk's variable-passing feature:

```
for i in {1..100}; do awk -F "," -v i=$i '{ i++; j=i+2; printf "%3d, %12.3f, %12.3f\n", $1, $i, $j }' All_Runs.csv > Run-$i.csv; done
```

(both untested)

Comment: Looks like the second one needs `i=i` → `i=$i`?

Answer (score 0):

Wait a minute, it does work if I type the command correctly ...

```
for i in {1..2} ; do awk -F "," " { printf \"%3d %12.3f %12.3f\\n\", \$1, \$($i+1), \$($i+3) } " All_Runs.csv ; done
```

Was missing the `; done`.  Doh!